# Can't Tranform Kafka Json Data in Spark Structured Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to get Kafka messages and processing it with Spark in standalone. Kafka stores data as json format. I can get Kafka messages but can not parse json data with defining schema.

When I run the `bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic my_kafka_topic --from-beginning` command to see the kafka messages in kafka topic, it outputs as follows:

```
"{\"timestamp\":1553792312117,\"values\":[{\"id\":\"Simulation.Simulator.Temperature\",\"v\":21,\"q\":true,\"t\":1553792311686}]}"
"{\"timestamp\":1553792317117,\"values\":[{\"id\":\"Simulation.Simulator.Temperature\",\"v\":22,\"q\":true,\"t\":1553792316688}]}"
```

And I can get this data succesfully with this code block in Spark:

```
df = spark \
.readStream \
.format("kafka") \
.option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
.option("subscribe", "my_kafka_topic") \
.load() \
.select(col("value").cast("string"))
```

The schema is like this:

```
df.printSchema()

root
 |-- value: string (nullable = true)
```

And then writing this dataframe to console and it prints the kafka messages:

```
Batch: 9
-------------------------------------------
+--------------------+
|               value|
+--------------------+
|"{\"timestamp\":1...|
+--------------------+
```

But I want to parse json data to define schema and the code block that I've tried to do it:

```
schema = StructType([ StructField("timestamp", LongType(), False), StructField("values", ArrayType( StructType([ StructField("id", StringType(), True), StructField("v", IntegerType(), False), StructField("q", BooleanType(), False), StructField("t", LongType(), False) ]), True ), True) ])

parsed = spark \
  .readStream \
  .format("kafka") \
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
  .option("subscribe", "my_kafka_topic") \
  .load() \
  .select(from_json(col("value").cast("string"), schema).alias("opc"))
```

And the schema of `parsed` dataframe:

```
parsed.printSchema()
root
  |-- opc: struct (nullable = true)
  |    |-- timestamp: string (nullable = true)
  |    |-- values: struct (nullable = true)
  |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
  |    |    |-- v: integer (nullable = true)
  |    |    |-- q: boolean (nullable = true)
  |    |    |-- t: string (nullable = true)
```

These code blocks run without error. But when I want to write `parsed` dataframe to the console:

```
query = parsed\
   .writeStream\
   .format("console")\
   .start()

query.awaitTermination()
```

it is writing `null` like this in console:

```
+----+
| opc|
+----+
|null|
+----+
```

So, it seems there is problem with parsing json data but can't figure out it.

Can you tell me what is wrong?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47912804/overloaded-method-value-apply-with-alternatives?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the schema was not correct for your case please try to apply the next one:

```
schema = StructType([ 
StructField("timestamp", LongType(), False), 
StructField("values", ArrayType(
    StructType([StructField("id", StringType(), True), 
    StructField("v", IntegerType(), False), 
    StructField("q", BooleanType(), False), 
    StructField("t", LongType(), False)]), True), True)])
```

Also remember that the `inferSchema` option works pretty well so you could let Spark discover the schema and save it.

Another issue is that your json data has leading and trailing double quotes `"` also it contains `\` those make an invalid JSON which was preventing Spark from parsing the message.

In order to remove the invalid characters your code should modified as next:

```
parsed = spark \
  .readStream \
  .format("kafka") \
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
  .option("subscribe", "my_kafka_topic") \
  .load() \
  .withColumn("value", regexp_replace(col("value").cast("string"), "\\\\", "")) \
  .withColumn("value", regexp_replace(col("value"), "^\"|\"$", "")) \
  .select(from_json(col("value"), schema).alias("opc"))
```

Now your output should be:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|value                                                                                                             |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"timestamp":1553588718638,"values":[{"id":"Simulation.Simulator.Temperature","v":26,"q":true,"t":1553588717036}]}|
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Good luck!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion or debugging sessions; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190880/discussion-on-answer-by-alexandros-biratsis-cant-tranform-kafka-json-data-in-sp). Please make sure that the answer has been [edit]ed to incorporate all relevant information.